# Upgrading Datastax Enterprise building new datacenter

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have cluster which is datastax-enterprise 4.8.2. Since "nodetool ugradesstables" commands takes too much time. I have an idea which is to add new datacenter of which version is 5.0.2. and remove the datacenter of which is 4.8.2. so I can start with fresh datacenter

Can I follow the idea?

Comment: Is this not the same question as your previous one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39557058/add-new-datacenter-during-datastax-upgrade-4-8-8-to-5-0-2

Comment: @markc actually it is not. In this question, I tried to ask that  I have DC1 which dse version 4.8.2. What if i build new datacenter which name is DC2  and dse version is 5.0.2. After adding this DC2 to cluster, then running nodetool rebuild DC1. Do i see SSTables old version or new version in DC2.

Comment: @markc In the other link, Can i add new datacenter, while upgrading proces is going on in DC1. Since i had performance issues in DC1.

Comment: I wouldn't add nodes while upgrading. You could run into streaming issues. Note the article I linked in that question about the upgrade limitations, changing cluster topology and schema etc should be done after you have upgraded