# add new datacenter during datastax upgrade 4.8.8 to 5.0.2

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have multiple datacenters. One of them is Cassandra other one is Solr datacenter. I already started upgrading process. Still 1 node is being upgrading since "upgradesstables" command have been taking for 4 days.

I want to add new cassandra datacenter and i dont have time to wait upgrading process is done. Can i add new cassandra datacenter with version 5.0.2 while there is upgrading process is going  on.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can run a cluster in a partially upgraded state, it is a transient state and not a situation you'd want your cluster to be in for any length of time. There's some operations you should avoid while the cluster is in a partially upgraded state and also your cluster will show a schema disagreement while in this state.

I would say its best to not add that new DC into the mix. Please see the upgrade limitations here:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-upgrade/upgrade/datastax_enterprise/upgdDSE50.html#upgdDSE50__restrictions

Comment: thanks @markc. I did not add new datacenter while upgrading process going on. Instead I run multiple upgradesstables command. But when it comes to big SSTables, upgrading process still slow even i set compaction unthrottle.

Comment: Yes `upgradesstables` can take a rather long time to run however the cluster will run while this operation is performing, so you could consider `upgradesstables` to be a "final" operation you carry out after the fact. You can read and write from / to the cluster but the upgrade is only complete once this final step is complete.